# Error : Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel

```
$total1 = DB::table('listrik_depan')->select('depan_pakaiwbp1200')->get();
$total2 = DB::table('listrik_belakang')->select('belakang_pakaiwbp60')->get();

$seluruh = $total1 + $total2;
dd($seluruh);
```

```
Error : Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int
```

Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: Please dont paste your question in the [answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71866735/4826457)

Answer (score 1):

`get()` return object of table not single value.

use like this way `DB::table('listrik_depan')->value('depan_pakaiwbp1200')` instead of `get()`

```
$total1 = DB::table('listrik_depan')->value('depan_pakaiwbp1200');
$total2 = DB::table('listrik_belakang')->value('belakang_pakaiwbp60');

$seluruh = $total1 + $total2;
dd($seluruh);
```